# Any resources to figure out the frequency with which words are used in combination with others?

Tags: resource

As an example among many others, I'm trying to figure out whether one could substitute 'die Beherrschung über eine Situation' for 'die Kontrolle über eine Situation', and although, e.g., dwds.de considers them to be synonyms, I'm wondering whether there are resources out there that could allow me to figure out how often certain combinations are seen together, without spending my days bothering natives hehe.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm confused by "considers them to be synonyms". Do you mean the phrases "Beherrschung/Kontrolle über eine Situation" or the words "Beherrschung" vs. "Kontrolle". Being synonyms does not imply being interchangeable; "pail" is a synonym for "bucket", but you don't say "kicked the pail". You may not have noticed that DWDS gives "die Beherrschung der Situation" as a usage example under "Beherrschung", to me that's an indication that it's a typical phrase using the word.

Comment: @RDBury Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section *Typische Verbindungen* of [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Situation) is a good first place to check. Neither *Beherrschung* nor *Kontrolle* shows up in the entry of *Situation*, unfortunately.

With more than basic knowledge of German you may resort to the word usage profiles of DWDS, which for *Situation* can be found here: [DWDS word profile: Situation](https://www.dwds.de/wp/Situation).

While *Kontrolle über eine Situation* may be the proper translation in some contexts, I consider *eine Situation unter Kontrolle haben* as the more common phrase; Google ngrams gives a frequency higher by a factor of more than 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references!

Answer (score 1):

That is literally what [Google Ngrams does](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A+%C3%BCber+eine+Situation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BKontrolle%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsich%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bschriftlich%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInformationen%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUrteil%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%9Cberblick%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bman%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBericht%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwir%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAussage%20%C3%BCber%20eine%20Situation%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Ngram graph for * über eine Situation]

I couldn't figure out why POS-tag wildcards don't work in German, otherwise a query like `*_NOUN über eine Situation` would be more appropriate.

In your case, [this search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Kontrolle+der+Situation%2C+Kontrolle+%C3%BCber+die+Situation%2C+Beherrschung+der+Situation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CKontrolle%20der%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CKontrolle%20%C3%BCber%20die%20Situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBeherrschung%20der%20Situation%3B%2Cc0) would probably more useful:

[image: Ngrams graph for Kontrolle/Beherrschung der Situation]

*Beherrschung über die Situation* is unidiomatic and never occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it was just as useful as the selected one!